# MySQL "sending data" activity take longer time

Tags: mysql, linux, query-optimization

I recently upgraded MySQL 5.1 to 5.7.8rc.

I have a unique issue with "sending data" status during profiling. It takes more time than expected for every complex or union queries (some time for simple queries also). I tried with best optimized as well as original query. Googled and tried all the possible configurations but no luck.

Query performs supper fast in MySQL 5.1, but not in 5.7.

Also tried with table optimization, analyze, repair etc..

## some details for reference:

- OS: Centos 6.9 64 bit
- MySQL: 5.7.8 rc
- CPU: 4
- RAM: 64 GB
- Data volume: 450 GB
- Type: Dedicated VM

## Query Profiling:

```
Status                  Duration
starting                0.000515
checking permissions    0.000023
checking permissions    0.000016
checking permissions    0.000014
checking permissions    0.000014
checking permissions    0.000014
checking permissions    0.000014
checking permissions    0.000014
checking permissions    0.000014
checking permissions    0.000016
checking permissions    0.000014
checking permissions    0.000019
Opening tables          0.000079
init                    0.000325
System lock             0.000068
optimizing              0.000079
statistics              0.001888
preparing               0.000151
Creating tmp table      0.000128
Sorting result          0.000027
optimizing              0.000034
statistics              0.000064
preparing               0.000047
Creating tmp table      0.000047
Sorting for group       0.000030
optimizing              0.000018
statistics              0.000022
preparing               0.000022
Creating tmp table      0.000043
Sorting for order       0.000023
executing               0.000016
Sending data            4.015596
Creating sort index     0.004766
executing               0.000010
Sending data            0.000159
executing               0.000008
Sending data            0.000025
Creating sort index     0.000349
end                     0.000010
query end               0.000024
removing tmp table      0.000013
query end               0.000011
removing tmp table      0.000008
query end               0.000009
removing tmp table      0.000011
query end               0.000009
removing tmp table      0.000007
query end               0.000010
removing tmp table      0.000008
query end               0.000006
closing tables          0.000026
freeing items           0.000039
removing tmp table      0.000009
freeing items           0.000067
logging slow query      0.000047
cleaning up             0.000042
```

## Execution Plan:

```
+----+--------------+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table       | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                       | key                | key_len | ref                                  | rows | filtered | Extra                              |
+----+--------------+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | TIGM_GRP    | NULL       | index  | PRIMARY,FLD_PARENT_GROUP_ID                         | PRIMARY            | 2       | NULL                                 |   87 |     0.33 | Using where                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | TIPLD       | NULL       | range  | FLD_PRICE_LEVEL_ID                                  | FLD_PRICE_LEVEL_ID | 3       | NULL                                 |   26 |    10.00 | Using index condition; Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | TIPLM       | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                             | PRIMARY            | 2       | TIPLD.FLD_PRICE_LEVEL_ID             |    1 |    10.00 | Using where                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | TIGL        | NULL       | ref    | FLD_GROUP_ID,fld_item_id                            | FLD_GROUP_ID       | 2       | TIGM_GRP.FLD_GROUP_ID                |  404 |   100.00 | NULL                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | TIM         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FLD_ITEM_TYPE,FLD_ADDON_ID,FLD_PRODUCT_TYPE | PRIMARY            | 4       | TIGL.FLD_ITEM_ID                     |    1 |    50.00 | Using where                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | TSIAM       | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                             | PRIMARY            | 4       | TIM.FLD_ADDON_ID                     |    1 |    10.00 | Using where                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | TSIARM      | NULL       | ref    | FLD_ADDON_ID                                        | FLD_ADDON_ID       | 5       | TIM.FLD_ADDON_ID                     |    1 |    10.00 | Using index condition; Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | TIPD        | NULL       | ref    | FLD_ITEM_ID,FLD_PRICE_LEVEL_ID                      | FLD_ITEM_ID        | 2       | TIM.FLD_ITEM_ID                      |    3 |     1.35 | Using index condition; Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | TIGM_PARENT | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                             | PRIMARY            | 2       | TIGM_GRP.FLD_PARENT_GROUP_ID         |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                        |
|  2 | UNION        | TIGM_GRP    | NULL       | index  | PRIMARY,FLD_PARENT_GROUP_ID                         | PRIMARY            | 2       | NULL                                 |   87 |     0.06 | Using where                        |
|  2 | UNION        | TIGM_PARENT | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                             | PRIMARY            | 2       | TIGM_GRP.FLD_PARENT_GROUP_ID         |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                        |
|NULL| UNION RESULT | <union1,2>  | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                                 | NULL |     NULL | Using temporary; Using filesort    |
+----+--------------+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
```

## my.cnf:

```
[mysql]
# CLIENT #######################################################################
port                            = 3306
socket                          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
# GENERAL ######################################################################
user                            = mysql
port                            = 3306
socket                          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
server_id                       = 32108
default_storage_engine          = InnoDB
pid_file                        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
optimizer_prune_level           = 0
optimizer_search_depth          = 0
max_length_for_sort_data        = 8388608 #New
net_buffer_length               = 1048576 #New
back_log                        = 80
symbolic-links                  = 0
log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1
net_read_timeout                = 10 #90
net_write_timeout               = 10 #120
net_retry_count                 = 30
thread_stack                    = 512K #192K
long_query_time                 = 10
tmpdir                          = /tmp

# MyISAM #######################################################################
key_buffer_size                 = 64M
read_buffer_size                = 32M
read_rnd_buffer_size            = 32M
bulk_insert_buffer_size         = 16M
myisam_sort_buffer_size         = 128M
myisam_max_sort_file_size       = 1G
myisam_repair_threads           = 1
memlock
max_allowed_packet              = 32M
max_connect_errors              = 100
sql_mode                        = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sysdate-is-now                  = 1
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1
innodb                          = FORCE
# Password policy disabled as per communication 05-Sep2017
validate_password               = OFF

# DATA STORAGE ##################################################################
datadir                         = /var/lib/mysql/

# BINARY LOGGING ################################################################
log-bin                         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days                = 14
sync-binlog                     = 1

# REPLICATION ###################################################################
skip-slave-start                = 1
relay-log                       = /var/log/mysql-realy-logs/relay-bin
slave-skip-errors               = 1062 #,1053,1032,1237,1146
slave-net-timeout               = 60
relay_log_purge                 = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #############################################################
tmp-table-size                  = 256M
max-heap-table-size             = 256M
query_cache_min_res_unit        = 12288 #8192 #New
query-cache-type                = 1
query-cache-size                = 32M #102400 #0 #256M
max-connections                 = 150
thread-cache-size               = 10 #-1 #Auto resized
open-files-limit                = 65535
table_definition_cache          = 2000
table_open_cache                = 4096 #3092
table_open_cache_instances      = 4
sort_buffer_size                = 128M
join_buffer_size                = 512M
binlog_cache_size               = 16M
query_cache_limit               = 4M

# INNODB ########################################################################
innodb_fast_shutdown            = 1
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_group_home_dir       = /mysql_redo_logs/mysql_redo_logs
innodb_log_files_in_group       = 2
innodb_log_file_size            = 1G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2
innodb_file_per_table           = 1 #ON
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 32G #20G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 32
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 64M
innodb_adaptive_hash_index      = 1 #ON
innodb_thread_concurrency       = 300 # "0" is default and means infinite (as and when needed). #250 #32
innodb_thread_sleep_delay       = 1
innodb_flush_neighbors          = 1
innodb_sync_array_size          = 832 # Default is 768
skip-innodb_doublewrite  #New
innodb_page_cleaners            = 32 # Must be =innodb_buffer_pool_instances
innodb_sort_buffer_size         = 512M
innodb_read_io_threads          = 64
innodb_write_io_threads         = 16
#innodb_concurrency_tickets      = 429496729
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct      = 90
innodb_lock_wait_timeout        = 10 #80
innodb_compression_level        = 0 #New
innodb_lru_scan_depth           = 512 #1024 #Default

# LOGGING #######################################################################
log_error                       = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes   = 1
slow_query_log                  = 1
log_error_verbosity             = 3

[mysqld_safe]
open-files-limit = 4096
malloc-lib                        = /usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 64M
```

So far I have tried most of the options, currently I started the service in caching mode for quick response.

Can you please help me fix this "sending data" delay issue

Comment: This is basically a query optimization question, but you haven't included the query!! You should always include the actual SQL query when you ask for help optimizing a query. Also include the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` of each table referenced in the query so we can see indexes, data types, constraints.

Comment: You should not use rc (Release candidates)  verions. Those versions arnt ready for production

Comment: As usual, Profile has nearly all the time under "Sending data".

Comment: Hi Raymond, thanks for your response.
I see MySQL rc releases be ing promoted for production
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/which-version.html
"rc indicates a Release Candidate (RC). Release candidates are believed to be stable, having passed all of MySQL's internal testing. New features may still be introduced in RC releases, but the focus shifts to fixing bugs to stabilize features introduced earlier within the series."
If I miss understood it, then can you please suggest me some less buggy 5.7 version? and few points as why

Answer (score 0):

A lot of Optimizer changes happened between 5.1 and 5.7.  For one thing, ICP is new; I see it several times in the `EXPLAIN`.  We need to see the query to discuss further.  If possible, get the `EXPLAIN` from 5.1.

Meanwhile, here are some minor comments on `my.cnf`:

```
thread_stack                    = 512K #192K
```

Generally, it is not useful to increase this setting.

```
optimizer_prune_level           = 0
optimizer_search_depth          = 0
```

What prompted you to set to 0?

```
innodb                          = FORCE
```

deprecated in 5.7.5; suggest removing before it becomes an error.

```
slave-skip-errors               = 1062 #,1053,1032,1237,1146
```

Sweeping gremlins under the rug -- you will stub your toes on they lump.

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 32G #20G
```

Unless you have some large apps on the same machine, 44G might be a little better.

```
innodb_page_cleaners            = 32 # Must be =innodb_buffer_pool_instances
```

re the comment -- Technically, it is auto-limited to pool_instances; see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_cleaners (Thanks, WilsonHauck)

```
log_queries_not_using_indexes   = 1
```

In my opinion, this clutters the slowlog.  The interesting entries are those that exceed `long_query_time`.  Do you have any interesting queries in the slowlog?

Comment: Thanks Rick, there could be loads of such queries, unfortunately the expectation is to get at lease the same performance as 5.1 if not more.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I will have my.cng changed. there could be loads of such queries, unfortunately the expectation is to get at lease the same performance as 5.1 if not more. do not have much time to optimize all old queries. for now please suggest me any tricky things that can improve it bit more without touching the queries. business expects that: it it is working in lower version, it should work better on higher version. is there a better way to avoid disk I/O and make "sending data" faster?.

Comment: Plan from 5.1
1  |PRIMARY |TIM  |ref  |PRIMARY,FLD_ITEM_TYPE,FLD_PRODUCT_TYPE,FLD_ADDON_ID  |FLD_PRODUCT_TYPE  |1  |const  |17054  |Using temporary; Using filesort
1  |PRIMARY |TIGL  |ref  |FLD_GROUP_ID,fld_item_id  |fld_item_id  |2  |TIM.FLD_ITEM_ID  |1  |Using where
1  |PRIMARY |TIGM_GRP  |eq_ref  |PRIMARY,FLD_PARENT_GROUP_ID  |PRIMARY  |2  |TIGL.FLD_GROUP_ID  |1  |Using where
1  |PRIMARY |TIGM_PARENT  |eq_ref  |PRIMARY  |PRIMARY  |2  |TIGM_GRP.FLD_PARENT_GROUP_ID  |1  |Using index
1  |PRIMARY |TSIAM  |eq_ref  |PRIMARY  |PRIMARY  |4  |TIM.FLD_ADDON_ID  |1  |Using where

Comment: 1  |PRIMARY |TSIARM  |ref  |FLD_ADDON_ID  |FLD_ADDON_ID  |5  |TSIAM.FLD_ADDON_ID  |1  |Using where
1  |PRIMARY |TIPD  |ref  |FLD_ITEM_ID,FLD_PRICE_LEVEL_ID  |FLD_ITEM_ID  |2  |TIM.FLD_ITEM_ID  |1  |Using where
1  |PRIMARY |TIPLD  |ref  |FLD_PRICE_LEVEL_ID  |FLD_PRICE_LEVEL_ID  |3  |TIPD.FLD_PRICE_LEVEL_ID  |1  |Using where
1  |PRIMARY |TIPLM  |eq_ref  |PRIMARY  |PRIMARY  |2  |TIPLD.FLD_PRICE_LEVEL_ID  |1  |Using where
2  |UNION   |TIGM_GRP  |index  |FLD_PARENT_GROUP_ID  |PRIMARY  |2  |  |87  |Using where

Comment: 2  |UNION   |TIGM_PARENT  |eq_ref  |PRIMARY  |PRIMARY  |2  |TIGM_GRP.FLD_PARENT_GROUP_ID  |1  |Using index
  |UNION RESULT |<union1,2>  |ALL |Using filesort

Comment: All the tables have key fields indexed,
SELECT 
    TIGM_GRP.C_GRP_ID AS GRP_ID,
    TIGM_GRP.C_NAME AS GRP_NAME,
    TIGM_GRP.C_LEAF_FLAG AS LEAF_FLAG,
    TIGM_GRP.C_LEVEL AS GRP_LEVEL,
    TIGM_GRP.C_LEFT_POSITION AS LEFT_POS,
    TIGM_GRP.C_RIGHT_POSITION AS RIGHT_POS,
    TIGM_GRP.C_PARENT_GRP_ID AS PARENT_ID,
    TIGM_GRP.C_STATE AS GRP_STATE,
    IF(TIGM_GRP.C_PARENT_GRP_ID = '43',
        0,
        1) AS GRP_INDENT,
    COUNT(DISTINCT TSIAM.C_ADDON_ID) AS ADDON_COUNT,
    FLOOR((TIGM_GRP.C_RIGHT_POSITION - TIGM_GRP.C_LEFT_POSITION) / 2) AS CHILD_COUNT,

Comment: TIGM_GRP.C_IMAGE_PATH AS IMAGE_PATH
FROM
    T_ITM_GRP_PARENT TIGM_GRP 
        INNER JOIN
    T_ITM_GRP_PARENT TIGM_PARENT ON TIGM_GRP.C_PARENT_GRP_ID = TIGM_PARENT.C_GRP_ID
        INNER JOIN
    T_ITM_GRP_LK TIGL ON TIGM_GRP.C_GRP_ID = TIGL.C_GRP_ID
        INNER JOIN
    T_ITM_PARENT TIM ON (TIGL.C_ITM_ID = TIM.C_ITM_ID
        AND TIM.C_FLAVOUR_TYPE = 2)
        INNER JOIN
    T_SD_IM_ADDON_PARENT TSIAM ON (TIM.C_ADDON_ID = TSIAM.C_ADDON_ID
        AND TSIAM.C_ADDON_STATUS = 1)
   INNER JOIN
    T_SD_IM_ADDON_RELEASE_PARENT TSIARM ON (TSIAM.C_ADDON_ID = TSIARM.C_ADDON_ID

Comment: AND TSIARM.C_STATUS = 1)
        INNER JOIN
    T_ITM_PRICE_DETAILS TIPD ON (TIM.C_ITM_ID = TIPD.C_ITM_ID
        AND TIPD.C_PURCHASE_TYPE = 1)
        INNER JOIN
    T_ITM_PRICE_LEVEL_PARENT TIPLM ON (TIPD.C_PRICE_LEVEL_ID = TIPLM.C_PRICE_LEVEL_ID
        AND TIPLM.C_COUNTRY_GRP_ID = '1')
        INNER JOIN
    T_ITM_PRICE_LEVEL_DETAILS TIPLD ON (TIPLD.C_PRICE_LEVEL_ID = TIPLM.C_PRICE_LEVEL_ID
        AND TIPD.C_PAYMENT_METHOD = TIPLD.C_PAYMENT_METHOD
        AND TIPD.C_CURRENCY_CODE = TIPLD.C_CURRENCY_CODE
        AND TIPLD.C_PAYMENT_METHOD = 2)

Comment: WHERE
    TIGM_GRP.C_LEVEL > '1'
        AND TIGM_GRP.C_TYPE = 20
        AND TIGM_GRP.C_STATE = 1
        AND IF(TSIAM.C_ADDON_COMMERCIAL_TYPE = 3,
        48,
        43) = TIM.C_ITM_TYPE
        AND IF(TSIAM.C_ADDON_COMMERCIAL_TYPE = 3,
        2,
        1) = TIM.C_LICENSE_TYPE
        AND IF(TSIAM.C_ADDON_COMMERCIAL_TYPE = 3,
        1,
        0) = TIM.C_NEW_SERIAL_FLAG
GRP BY TIGM_GRP.C_GRP_ID

Comment: UNION SELECT 
    TIGM_GRP.C_GRP_ID AS GRP_ID,
    TIGM_GRP.C_NAME AS GRP_NAME,
    TIGM_GRP.C_LEAF_FLAG AS LEAF_FLAG,
    TIGM_GRP.C_LEVEL AS GRP_LEVEL,
    TIGM_GRP.C_LEFT_POSITION AS LEFT_POS,
    TIGM_GRP.C_RIGHT_POSITION AS RIGHT_POS,
    TIGM_GRP.C_PARENT_GRP_ID AS PARENT_ID,
    TIGM_GRP.C_STATE AS GRP_STATE,
    IF(TIGM_GRP.C_PARENT_GRP_ID = '43',
        0,
        1) AS GRP_INDENT,
    0 AS ADDON_COUNT,
    FLOOR((TIGM_GRP.C_RIGHT_POSITION - TIGM_GRP.C_LEFT_POSITION) / 2) AS CHILD_COUNT,
    TIGM_GRP.C_IMAGE_PATH AS IMAGE_PATH

Comment: FROM
    T_ITM_GRP_PARENT TIGM_GRP
        INNER JOIN
    T_ITM_GRP_PARENT TIGM_PARENT ON TIGM_GRP.C_PARENT_GRP_ID = TIGM_PARENT.C_GRP_ID
WHERE
    TIGM_GRP.C_LEVEL > '1'
        AND TIGM_GRP.C_TYPE = 20
        AND TIGM_GRP.C_STATE = 1
        AND TIGM_GRP.C_LEAF_FLAG = 0
GRP BY TIGM_GRP.C_GRP_ID
ORDER BY LEFT_POS;

Comment: Please go through the tutorial so you can get enough reputation so you can edit your question and put the EXPLAINs in a more readable format.

Comment: @WilsonHauck -- Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone
I think I figured out the issue.
1) 5.6 the optimization engine and plan generated is a result mixture of meta-data and user query (non relational joins). engine trusts user and get best plan.
But 5.7 does not trust soft relations between the tables though they are indexed.
2) 5.7 expects explicit data integrity and do not believe on user.

**POC:**
I created the same tables involved with hard FK references, **wala !** found a miraculous response. the same query which executed without FK took 6.085 Sec (sending data),
and the query with data integrity enforced took 0.05 Sec (with no change in indexing).

So I think 5.7 expects strong data integrity constraints explicitly.